# Which p-adic groups are simply-connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose that we are working over a nonarchimedean local field $F$, for instance $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Which semisimple algebraic groups (or Lie groups) over $F$ are simply-connected? In particular, I am interested in when the theorem of Iwahori-Matsumoto on a double coset decomposition with respect to an Iwahori subgroup applies.

Comment: If you are using the standard topological definition of "simply connected", then because such groups are always totally disconnected, meaning that every point is a connected component, it follows that they are never simply connected.

Comment: Well you're right, with this definitione these groups would never be simply connected. If $F$ is algebraically closed, the correct definition is that the character group of the torus is the full weight lattice.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with working over a nonarchimedean field.  Any semi-simple group (say over a field of char. zero, to be safe --- although it's probably not necessary) has a finite centre.   In its isogeny class, there is a group with largest possible centre, and one with trivial centre (the *adjoint group* in the given isogeny class).

For classical groups, $SL_n$ and $Sp_n$ are simply connected.   The groups $SO_n$ are not; they have spin double covers which are simply connected.    The groups $SU_n$ are twists of $SL_n$, and so are also simply connected.